# PyTorch: Testing with torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder and DataLoader

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm a newbie trying to make this PyTorch CNN work with the [Cats&Dogs dataset from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/). As there are no targets for the test images, I manually classified some of the test images and put the class in the filename, to be able to test (maybe should have just used some of the train images).

I used the torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder class to load the train and test images. The training seems to work.

But what do I need to do to make the test-routine work? I don't know, how to connect my test_data_loader with the test loop at the bottom, via test_x and test_y.

The Code is based on [this MNIST example CNN.](https://github.com/MorvanZhou/PyTorch-Tutorial/blob/master/tutorial-contents/401_CNN.py) There, something like this is used right after the loaders are created. But I failed to rewrite it for my dataset:

```
test_x = Variable(torch.unsqueeze(test_data.test_data, dim=1), volatile=True).type(torch.FloatTensor)[:2000]/255.   # shape from (2000, 28, 28) to (2000, 1, 28, 28), value in range(0,1)
test_y = test_data.test_labels[:2000]
```

The Code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.utils.data as data
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms

EPOCHS = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 10
LEARNING_RATE = 0.003
TRAIN_DATA_PATH = "./train_cl/"
TEST_DATA_PATH = "./test_named_cl/"
TRANSFORM_IMG = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(256),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                         std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225] )
    ])

train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=TRAIN_DATA_PATH, transform=TRANSFORM_IMG)
train_data_loader = data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True,  num_workers=4)
test_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=TEST_DATA_PATH, transform=TRANSFORM_IMG)
test_data_loader  = data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=4) 

class CNN(nn.Module):
    # omitted...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("Number of train samples: ", len(train_data))
    print("Number of test samples: ", len(test_data))
    print("Detected Classes are: ", train_data.class_to_idx) # classes are detected by folder structure

    model = CNN()    
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
    loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()    

    # Training and Testing
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):        
        for step, (x, y) in enumerate(train_data_loader):
            b_x = Variable(x)   # batch x (image)
            b_y = Variable(y)   # batch y (target)
            output = model(b_x)[0]          
            loss = loss_func(output, b_y)   
            optimizer.zero_grad()           
            loss.backward()                 
            optimizer.step()

            # Test -> this is where I have no clue
            if step % 50 == 0:
                test_x = Variable(test_data_loader)
                test_output, last_layer = model(test_x)
                pred_y = torch.max(test_output, 1)[1].data.squeeze()
                accuracy = sum(pred_y == test_y) / float(test_y.size(0))
                print('Epoch: ', epoch, '| train loss: %.4f' % loss.data[0], '| test accuracy: %.2f' % accuracy)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looking at the data from Kaggle and your code, it seems that there are problems in your data loading, both train and test set. First of all, the data should be in a different folder per label for the default PyTorch `ImageFolder` to load it correctly. In your case, since all the training data is in the same folder, PyTorch is loading it as one class and hence learning seems to be working. You can correct this by using a folder structure like - `train/dog`, - `train/cat`, - `test/dog`, - `test/cat` and then passing the train and the test folder to the train and test `ImageFolder` respectively. The training code seems fine, just change the folder structure and you should be good. Take a look at the official documentation of [ImageFolder](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder) which has a similar example.

Comment: What if I have all images in one folder and I want the classes to be set by a CSV file I have? What should I do?

Comment: @Royi I don't think there is any direct way to do that yet (that I know of). But you can extend the dataset class and do that. Here is an example from an official [PyTorch tutorial](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html#dataset-class). You can modify it and remove the extra stuff and it should work fine. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 5):

As per @Monster's comment above here is my folder structure for ImageFolder

[image]

And this how I load the dataset:

```
    train_dataset=datasets.ImageFolder(root="./root/",transform=train_transforms)
```