# How to link labels to pictures and feed them into a training function in Pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to build a classifier that classifies sign language gesture images. have folder with sub folders as follows
1) Train
2) Validation
3) Test

Each sub folder has folders named A through I. Those folder names are the labels to pictures within those folders.

I'm not really sure how can link those labels to pictures and feed them into the model.

Most of the Pytorch documentation online uses built in datasets and for someone new to this area, it is difficult to understand what is happening behind the scene. I have read about dataloaders, datasets, ImageFolder. I just started deep learning recently and splitting data was easy in machine learning using built in functions and pandas columns, not as much with pictures..

All I was able to do was those two functions but not sure how to proceed from there:

The first function is to load training pictures

```
    data_path = 'C:/Users/.../Train/'
    train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(
        root=data_path,
        transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
    )
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset,
        batch_size=10,
        num_workers=0,
        shuffle=True
    )
    return train_loader
```

The second function is to extract the labels from the pictures names within one specific folder, filenames have the convention of uselessinfo_letter_uselessnumbers

```
import os
data_path = r"C:\Users...\small_sample"
labels = []
for img_filename in os.listdir(data_path):
    if img_filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        useless1, letter, useless2 = img_filename.split('.')[0].split('_')
        labels.append(letter)
```

I'm looking to create a train_loader and I guess that train_loader would have both the tensor format of pictures with their labels.

to feed into

```
for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
            # Get the inputs
            inputs, labels = data
            labels = normalize_label(labels) # Convert labels to 0/1
            # Zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # Forward pass, backward pass, and optimize
            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels.float())
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
```

Comment: You can look at PyTorch's ImageFolder. It loads dataset with each class stored in a separate folder. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49087269/7615877)

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I like to write the dataloader for myself since it's easy to customize the data loading process what i really want.

Here is a dataloader i wrote before to load the seperated `.npy` files into the memory as the train/eval data.
https://github.com/FesianXu/SkeletonGCN/blob/master/feeder/ntu_feeder.py

In this code, I need to prepare the train/eval index at first, I will save the index files as `.npy` files and load them in `__init__()`, and then, the `__getitem__` method can be treated same no matter you are in training or evaluating, since you already make specific index. For more information, check the code and hope you can finally find out.