# How to split data into train and test sets from one directory with PyTorch?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, training-data, torchvision

I have a data folder that doesn't have data split into train and test folders. How do I split the data into train and test sets? The labels come from the names of the files, so any change in that order would have to include the labels. I want to split the data before using ImageFolder so the different transforms can be done on train and test datasets.

```
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomRotation(10),
                                       transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
                                       transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                                       transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                                                            [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])

test_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(256),
                                      transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                                      transforms.ToTensor(),
                                      transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                                                           [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])

train_image_dataset =  datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir, transform=train_transforms)

test_image_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir, transform=test_transforms)

train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_image_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

test_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_image_dataset, batch_size=32)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Cross-Validation , check this [answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-best-way-to-apply-k-fold-cross-validation-in-cnn/15035). You can add a column with the labels and then apply any cross-validation method to split into test and train.

Comment: Being able to do k-fold cross validation would be even better, but I don't see how that shows how to split with or before using ImageFolder, so certain transforms are only applied to the training set.

Comment: Okay, so I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073799/pytorch-testing-with-torchvision-datasets-imagefolder-and-dataloader). Hope this helps, earlier I thought you were looking for a concept.

Answer (score -1):

To split Image files to train and test you can use, ImageDataGenerator from tensorflow,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

#1st your image directory
files_dir = "imagefiles/rootdirectory"
image_size = (96,96)
Batch_size = 32

# create your Image data generator object with the normalization and other transformations you need you can review 
#all the transformations you can do from the link at the end
#create your training data generator with your splitting percentage !!!!
#Immportant thing if your are using a multiclass dataset parameter class_mode should be "categorical"

training_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = (1/256),validation_split = 0.3)
validation_gen = ImageDataGenrator(rescale = (1/256),validation_split = 0.3)
Training_set = training_gen.flow_from_directory(files_dir,
                                              batch_size =Batch_size,
                                            target_size = Image_size,
                                              class_mode="binary")

Validation_set = validation_gen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,
                                                target_size = Image_size,
                                                batch_size = Batch_size,
                                                class_mode = "binary")
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator

Comment: please read the title of the question... it is Pytorch and not Tensorflow